# Cannot resolve de.jplag.java.Language(), trying to use the JPlag API

Tags: java

I'm trying to learn how to use the API but keep running into this error, all I did was copy paste the example code

```
Language language = new de.jplag.java.Language();
        Set<File> submissionDirectories = Set.of(new File("/path/to/rootDir"));
        File baseCode = new File("/path/to/baseCode");
        JPlagOptions options = new JPlagOptions(language, submissionDirectories, Set.of()).withBaseCodeSubmissionDirectory(baseCode);

        JPlag jplag = new JPlag(options);
        try {
            JPlagResult result = jplag.run();

            // Optional
            ReportObjectFactory reportObjectFactory = new ReportObjectFactory();
            reportObjectFactory.createAndSaveReport(result, "/path/to/output");
        } catch (ExitException e) {
            // error handling here
        }
```

This is the version I'm using

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.jplag</
    <artifactId>jplag</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another dependency on the pom.xml file for the language that you are going to process. In your case, for java, you nedd to add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.jplag</groupId>
    <artifactId>java</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Do not remove your current dependency, you will need both.